# GCP Cloud Run : Application exec likely failed

Tags: google-cloud-run

I am running a service on GCP Cloud Run.

I found on the logs this error, how can I troubleshoot it?

What does it mean?

```
Application exec likely failed

terminated: Application failed to start: not available
```

[image]

Comment: Does the application start and expose an HTTP port on the defined port? 8080 by default

Comment: yes, the application starts,

Comment: It start with a port exposed?

Comment: yes, only few requests are failing with this error

Comment: What's your average startup time (cold start)?

Comment: I will investigate this

Comment: @marian.viadoi, I posted answer. Is it helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using Cloud Run Second Generation.

According to the official documentation:

```
During Preview, although the second generation execution environment
generally performs faster under sustained load, 
it has longer cold start times than the first generation.
```

Therefore, I switched back to First Generation.

Answer (score 1):

This error can be caused when containers fail to deploy/start.
To troubleshoot the issue, You may try to follow the steps mentioned in [document](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#container-failed-to-start).

As described in the document, if you build your container image on an ARM based machine, then it might not work as expected when used with Cloud Run. If so you can solve this issue, by following doc [build your image using Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/building/containers#builder).

To get the detailed logs, I would suggest setting up Cloud Logging with your Cloud Run.You can easily do so by following this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/logging) and [Setting up cloud logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup).

This will allow you to have more control over the logs that appear for your Cloud Run application.